# Distributing identical objects in distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible ways can we distribute 8 identical objects in 5 different boxes?

The possible answers are (A) 17820, (B) 6720, (C) 2475, (D) 1188 and (E) 495.

It seems like the correct answer should be (E) 495.

But I tried $\frac{n!}{(n-p)!} = \frac{8!}{(8-5)!}$ which equals 6720 (B).

Which one is the correct answer?

Comment: Why do you think it's 495?

Comment: It's the test's "official answer" for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be 
\begin{align}
\binom{8+4}{4}= 495.
\end{align}
Suppose you have 5 distinct boxes, then there are four walls. Hence if you line up the balls and the walls, then there are 12 choose 4 ways to put the walls between the balls.

Comment: I see, so it should be 12!/(4!*8!). The concept seems anti-intuitive to me though.

Comment: Once you have the picture then it will be all clear.